# Facebook social sigin-in javascript sdk won't load in Chrome or FF

Tags: javascript, facebook, angular, facebook-javascript-sdk

**Update 1**

I started with [angular quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) and only added `facebook`'s javascript, however, it won't load:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

---

I am Using Facebook JavaScript API to create login in an `angular 2` app, but running into the following:

> TypeError: FB.login is not a function

**index.html** (Elided for brevity)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>

<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function (err) {console.error(err);});
</script>
```

I noticed the script does not seem to load correctly, following is from Chrome `devtools`:

[image]

**Angular 2 Component**

```
declare const FB: any;

@Component({
  // usual suspects here
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor() {
  FB.init({
    appId: 'my-app-id',
    cookie: false,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.5'
  });    
 }

 ngOnInit(): void {    
    FB.getLoginStatus(response => {
      ....
    });
 }

 onSignin(socialMedia: string): void {
   FB.login(); // The errant line
 }
}
```

Am I supposed to do something like the following? [as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881573/uncaught-typeerror-fb-login-is-not-a-function)

```
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.com/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: can you confirm whether you can reach the file from your browser?

Comment: @Pengyy, The script won't load in chrome or firefox. Thought I would never have an occasion to say this, but, "It works in Microsoft Edge". I'm going to update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering this for the benefit of others....

It was [ghostery](https://www.ghostery.com/) plugin which was (among other things) blocking 'social signin'.

Answer (score 0):

i think insert script library of fb in your main html file.Also make sure that the script provided by the fb developers are inserted in your code that solve the problem.follow the link **https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart**

Comment: Well then in my case i faced the same problem at that time i comment out the code FB.login are run the project and after that remove the comment and then it work fine for me try it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't run FB.init directly, You should do:

```
declare var window:any;
```

and then in your constructor or ngInit Method use FB Async Method:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId: appID,
              xfbml: true,
              version: 'v2.5'
            });
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.com/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

fbAsyncInit automatically get trigger when facebook sdk loads.

See more at [Facebook quick start](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart)

Comment: It was ghostery which was blocking the script from loading.